# pr2_odometry errors when making pr2_mechanism_controllers

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to use pr2_gazebo.  I get the following errors when making pr2_mechanism_controllers.  Is pr2_odometry stable?

/home/ros_stacks/pr2_mechanism_controllers/src/pr2_odometry.cpp:392: error: ‘class controller::OdomMatrix16x1’ has no member named ‘cwise’
/home/ros_stacks/pr2_mechanism_controllers/src/pr2_odometry.cpp: In member function ‘controller::OdomMatrix3x1 controller::Pr2Odometry::iterativeLeastSquares(const controller::OdomMatrix16x3&, const controller::OdomMatrix16x1&, const std::string&, const int&)’:
/home/ros_stacks/pr2_mechanism_controllers/src/pr2_odometry.cpp:426: error: ‘SVD’ is not a member of ‘Eigen’
/home/ros_stacks/pr2_mechanism_controllers/src/pr2_odometry.cpp:426: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
/home/ros_stacks/pr2_mechanism_controllers/src/pr2_odometry.cpp:426: error: ‘svdOfFit’ was not declared in this scope
/home/ros_stacks/pr2_mechanism_controllers/src/pr2_odometry.cpp:454: error: ‘class controller::OdomMatrix16x1’ has no member named ‘cwise'

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11170/pr2_odometry-errors-when-making-pr2_mechanism_controllers/) by [Paul0nc](https://answers.ros.org/users/1067/paul0nc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 271 on 2011-09-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Problem solved by installing wg_robots_gazebo all at once.  Thanks to joq for the tip in an earlier (indirectly related) post.

---

Originally posted by [Paul0nc](https://answers.ros.org/users/1067/paul0nc/) with karma: 271 on 2011-09-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1